# How, do I select the best match for a string in multiple documents, where the score is equal for both?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, matching, elm, text-processing

I have implemented an algorithm in [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/), where I compare a sentence (user input) to other multiple sentences (data). The algorithm is working in such a manner, where the user input and the data is converted to words, and then I compare them by words. the algorithm will mark any sentence from the data, which has the most words in the user input, as the best match.

Now, at the first run, the first sentence from the data will be counted as the best match and then going to the second sentence and looks for matches. If the matches number is greater than the previous one, then the second sentence will be counted as the best match, otherwise the previous one.

In case, if there are equal matches in two sentences, then currently I am comparing the size of these two sentences and select the one, which has the smaller size, as the best match.

There is no semantic meaning involved, so is this the best way to select the best match, which has the smaller size in this case? or are there some other better options available? I have tried to look for some scientific references, but couldn't find any.

**Edit:**

To summarize, if you want to compare one sentence to two other sentences, based on word occurrences, If both of the sentences have the same number of words, which also exist in your comparing sentence, then which one can be marked as the most similar? which methods are used to retrieve this similarity?

Comment: For what I understand, you are looking for what's called a "string metric". There's a lot of them and they provide different results, so I don't know which is the best for your case. Wikipedia provide a list : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric.

Comment: [This survey](https://www.mdpi.com/2078-2489/11/9/421) of text similarity measures can be helpful too. You'll find lots of different approaches and algorithms for a wide range of use-cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some factors you can add in to improve the comparison:

- String similarity (eg. Levensthein, Jaro-Winkler, ...)
- Add a parameter for the sentence length by adding a linear or geometric penalty for a different sentence length (either on character or on word level)
- Clean the strings (remove stopwords, special signs etc.)
- Add the sequence (position) of words as a parameter. Thus which word is before/after another word.
- Use Sentence Embeddings for similarity to also capture some semantics (https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/08/top-4-sentence-embedding-techniques-using-python/)

Finally, there will always be some sentences that have the same difference to your input, although they are different. That's OK, as long as they are actually similarly different to your input sentence.

Comment: Good suggestions! Please have a look at this example. and tell me which one is the best match for my input. in the example, searchString is my input, and data is my other two sentences. https://ellie-app.com/c3rmr2yq8Fza1 There are three words in both sentences, which also exist in my input. you can think of any example. I am comparing based on the number of the words. How can Levenshtein or Jaro help in this case?

Comment: Well the number of words can be very missleading because words in between can be different, words may be written in different ways etc.

For example:I am playing football

Comment: Well the number of words can be very missleading because words in between can be different, words may be written in different ways etc.

In your example, the two sentences have exactly one word difference to the input word, so it is OK if they have the same similarity, since you compare on a word level.

Example:
Jaro Winkler and Levenshtein would make "I am playing football" more similar to "I'm playing futball" than "I am playing the drums". A strict word count would make "I am playing the drums" more similar.

While there is stemming, it usually does not work well in production.

Comment: The most advanced of the methods I talked about would be BERT (Transformers). Since they are trained on a corpus, they can also handle meaning. Thus "I am playing football" would be more similar to "I'm playing soccer" than to "I am playing the drums" because the embedding model learned, that soccer and football are very similar. This is quite advanced and probably a little too much for your project.

I would advice you to go with Jaro-Winkler because it is rather simple to implement while it can still handle typos :)

Comment: Please try to understand my problem. you understood the example, that is good. Now, please tell me which of the above is more similar to my input and why? please do not mention any distance algorithm or machine learning techniques. OK, I will give you a hint. Is that OK to return the smallest one as the best match? for example the second sentence's length is smaller, so that is more similar? If the length is not involved then tell me something else.

Comment: I would not take the sentence with the smaller length in general.
I would take the sentence with the more similar length to the input sentence (number of words). Thus if the input sentence is very long, one sentence is short, one sentence is very long and the number of similar words are the same, I would pick the second sentence, since it is also a long sentence. If the sentences have the same number of words, it really doesn't matter.
You can randomly choose any of them, since both have the same similarity to the input sentence.
It is also OK to return the smallest one as best match.